# Why am I not getting correct human readable date and time value from my epoch value?

Tags: java, datetime, epoch

I want to bulk convert my epoch values into human readable date and time value. Taking a value 1342179766, I converted it on [epoch-converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) and got Fri, 13 Jul 2012 11:42:46 GMT as answer which I know is correct. Now I used the java code provided on their site to convert it into date and time format but I am getting wrong answer.
Code:

```
String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date (1342179766*1000));
System.out.println(date);
```

Output:

```
12/07/1969 09:40:02
```

I looked at other questions on stackoverflow but mostly this code is given everywhere. I found 2-3 other code but all of them are also giving me same output.

Comment: yup! I tried that, got this as output 01/16/1970 18:19:39

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you should use `1342179766L*1000L` instead of `1342179766*1000`.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue comes from the fact that Java is trying to do integer multiplication on `1342179766*1000` and *then* convert it into a long. If you explicitly make this a long, then it works:

```
String date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new java.util.Date (1342179766L*1000));
System.out.println(date);
```